How to define same credentials for multiple feeds in nuget.config?
In my nuget.config I want to avoid duplicating username + access token combination for many different package sources that all lead to the same (artifactory) server. Is it possible to define packageSourceCredentials for multiple packageSources entries (e.g. using a glob) or can I define credentials for a certain server base address, e.g. for all requests to https://artifactory.mycompany.com/api/nuget/* ?
Background:

We have a company artifactory server, where all teams can host their nuget feeds. Authentication required. Access tokens expire each year.
For each project in our team we define required <packageSources> in a project-local nuget.config file such that each solution only pulls packages from the relevant feeds (it's too slow otherwise). Those config files are committed into git repositories, so that all developers (and CI server) can pull the required packages during build. Consequently access tokens are not part of this local nuget config file.
Each developer has to store his artifactory access token + username in his userspace nuget config, which is not committed anywhere.
Problem: each time one developer adds a new nuget feed, package restore fails for all other team members until they duplicate their token in their userspace nuget config for the new feed.

Microsoft suggests to use a credential provider, which is not available for artifactory to the best of my knowledge/research. The nuget config documentation did not give a clear hint how to define credentials for multiple(!) sources. I found different reasons for nuget setApiKey but eventually its used for something else. The documentation seems to contradict actual results on my machine (key and value swapped?). All my attempts to make my generated apikey work with Visual Studio failed with 403 forbidden responses.
